How to track down birth certificate of my grandmother from a town that changed borders during the war (Poland/Russia)?
I’m trying to locate my grandmother’s birth certificate from a town that frequently changed between Russian and Polish control during the early 20th century, particularly around the time of World War I and the interwar period. Which likely affected record-keeping.
We believe my grandmother, who passed away in 2009, was born in 1920. During the war, she used forged documents to navigate the difficult circumstances, and after the war, she lived under refugee status in Switzerland until her passing, so we never had her original birth certificate.
I’m interested in the best methods for tracking down her birth certificate. Are there specific archives, databases, or record types I should focus on that account for the shifting borders?

I suspect the chances of your question being answered would go up greatly if you included the name of the Russian/Polish town where you think she was born within your question.

@PolyGeo Oof. Well, the bummer part of the situation is that we don't know the town, but we suspect maybe in the Poland / Belarus bordering areas.

If you know your grandmother's real maiden name, try checking it on Russian sites for World War I participants and the "Memory of the People" website for World War II veterans. The surname's distribution might give clues about where her family or relatives lived, which can help in your search. If you also know her father's name and surname, look him up on sites too. Or may be, your grandmother ever mention any relatives, along with their names or places of residence - That information could further aid your research.
